# How do I prevent my ASP.NET MVC application from wanting to register the user after Google OAuth?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-oauth

I successfully authenticate with google, but I'm getting a failed message here (default code):

[image]

It then wants me to register my email to an account, but tells me my account already exists.  How do I skip the step and just auto associate with the matching email in my DB?

[image]

Any and all help greatly appreciated!  I don't know why I can't figure this out -.-

**EDIT**: I figured it out lol. But is it safe?

```
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
         return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
         return View("Lockout");

    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
         return RedirectToAction("SendCode",
                                 new { 
                                          ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
                                          RememberMe = false 
                                     });

    case SignInStatus.Failure:
    default:
         ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
         ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;

         // My code 
         var existingUser = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(loginInfo.Email);

         if (existingUser != null)
         {
             await SignInManager.SignInAsync(existingUser,
                                             isPersistent: false,
                                             rememberBrowser: false);
             return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
         }

         // end of my code

         return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation",
                     new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel 
                         { 
                             Email = loginInfo.Email 
                         });
}
```

Comment: "I've managed to connect my user to Google, but is it safe?" - that really is a 1984 question or not?

Comment: I mean is the way i did it particularly vulnerable lol.. i think it is so i'm working on something else.